# pass parameter in http get request not work

Tags: php, xamarin

I have the following code to get data from server, and I want to pass parameter with the request, how to do that in correct way in client side and server side

```
 string type = Intent.GetStringExtra("cartypeselect");
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"http://reksha.com/Coordinates/driversLocations.php", type));

        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Method = "GET";
        var content = "";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content);
                }
                Assert.NotNull(content);
            }
```

The PHP code

```
    $cartype= $_GET['type'];
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from drivers where status='online' and latitude is not null and longitude is not null and car_type='$cartype'")
```

Comment: Quick code review comment: Use response.IsSuccessStatusCode rather than checking for OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using String.Format correctly.  You have to specify a placeholder token in order to include your parameter.  You are also not correctly formatting your url

```
string.Format("http://reksha.com/Coordinates/driversLocations.php?type={0}", type);
```

Comment: This only applies to GET. And you should UrlEncode or UrlPathEncode the values, and use string interpolation, not string.Format.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a good article on how to use HttpClient. In their example, they're using a shared client object. Normally, you would wrap it in a using statement, though.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client